# Using boost: __func_Grm00gZzHB Function invoked with incorrect arguments

Tags: biicode

I have a problem to use boost with biicode. I have a simple project with a main. The project uses boost. In order to get boost with biicode I used the following cmake file:

```
include(biicode/boost/setup)
ADD_BII_TARGETS()

bii_find_boost(COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(${BII_BLOCK_TARGET} INTERFACE     ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${BII_BLOCK_TARGET} INTERFACE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

If I now call "bii configure", boost is downloaded and extracted (i checked the .biicode/boost folder). Nevertheless I get some weired errors (A trace version can be found [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SrTobi/f3406e8cee85b2fc391f/raw/boost%20biicode%20log)) and the configuration process fails:

```
$ bii configure --verbose
DEBUG: Everything up to date

DEBUG: No valid files found in d:\C++\Workspace\testx\blocks
INFO: Processing changes...
Running: "cmake"  -G "Visual Studio 12" -Wno-dev  ..\cmake

                BLOCK: user/testx
-----------------------------------------------------------
CMake Error at C:/Users/Tobi/AppData/Local/Temp/file_make_temporary_m6QEuq5c7B.tmp:1 (__func_1111111111):
  __func_1111111111 Function invoked with incorrect arguments for function
  named: __func_1111111111
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Tobi/AppData/Local/Temp/file_make_temporary_m6QEuq5c7B.tmp:4 (include)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmake/task/task_run_next.cmake:34 (eval)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmake/task/task_run_next.cmake:42 (task_run_next)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmake/task/task_run_all.cmake:6 (task_run_next)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmakepp.cmake:110 (task_run_all)
  ../deps/boost/install/build_jobs.cmake:1 (include)
  ../deps/boost/install/install.cmake:2 (include)
  ../deps/biicode/boost/setup.cmake:1 (include)
  ../../CMakeLists.txt:1 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/Tobi/AppData/Local/Temp/file_make_temporary_m6QEuq5c7B.tmp:1 (__func_6oohAf7Azh):
  __func_6oohAf7Azh Function invoked with incorrect arguments for function
  named: __func_6oohAf7Azh
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Tobi/AppData/Local/Temp/file_make_temporary_m6QEuq5c7B.tmp:4 (include)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmake/task/task_run_next.cmake:34 (eval)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmake/task/task_run_all.cmake:6 (task_run_next)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmakepp.cmake:110 (task_run_all)
  ../deps/boost/install/build_jobs.cmake:1 (include)
  ../deps/boost/install/install.cmake:2 (include)
  ../deps/biicode/boost/setup.cmake:1 (include)
  ../../CMakeLists.txt:1 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/Tobi/AppData/Local/Temp/file_make_temporary_m6QEuq5c7B.tmp:1 (__func_F9SWokvms4):
  __func_F9SWokvms4 Function invoked with incorrect arguments for function
  named: __func_F9SWokvms4
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Tobi/AppData/Local/Temp/file_make_temporary_m6QEuq5c7B.tmp:4 (include)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmake/task/task_run_next.cmake:34 (eval)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmake/task/task_run_all.cmake:6 (task_run_next)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmakepp.cmake:110 (task_run_all)
  ../deps/boost/install/build_jobs.cmake:1 (include)
  ../deps/boost/install/install.cmake:2 (include)
  ../deps/biicode/boost/setup.cmake:1 (include)
  ../../CMakeLists.txt:1 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/Tobi/AppData/Local/Temp/file_make_temporary_m6QEuq5c7B.tmp:1 (__func_Grm00gZzHB):
  __func_Grm00gZzHB Function invoked with incorrect arguments for function
  named: __func_Grm00gZzHB
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Tobi/AppData/Local/Temp/file_make_temporary_m6QEuq5c7B.tmp:4 (include)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmake/task/task_run_next.cmake:34 (eval)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmake/task/task_run_all.cmake:6 (task_run_next)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmakepp.cmake:110 (task_run_all)
  ../deps/boost/install/build_jobs.cmake:1 (include)
  ../deps/boost/install/install.cmake:2 (include)
  ../deps/biicode/boost/setup.cmake:1 (include)
  ../../CMakeLists.txt:1 (include)


+ LIB: user_testx
+ EXE: user_testx___main
-- No linking type specified. Assuming static linking
-- Setting up biicode Boost configuration...
-- Building Boost 1.57.0 components with toolset msvc-12.0...
Starting unit_test_framework library build job...
Building Boost components, please wait [                                         ]
Finished building unit_test_framework library
-- Boost version: 1.57.0
-- Boost version: 1.57.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   unit_test_framework
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/C++/Workspace/testx/bii/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
ERROR: CMake failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I failed to figure out what the problem was, but i fixed it^^. The problem was something with a binary symbol RS (E1 (hex) in ascii) which was placed in some source files of https://github.com/toeb/cmakepp (must be a cmake problem, because after removing them they appeared again after executing cmake).

The problem disappeared after updating cmake from version `3.1.0-rc1` -> `3.3.0-rc3`.